# React issues with reading a value in a context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have this context:

FilterProvider.tsx

```
import React, { createContext, useRef } from "react";

interface IFiltersContext {
  filters: { [key: string]: any };
  updateFilter: (name: string, value: any) => void;
  addFilter: (name: string, value: any) => void;
  clearFilter: (name: string) => void;
}

type FilterContextProps = {
  initialFilters?: any;
  onFilterChange: (values: any) => void;
};

export const FiltersContext = createContext<IFiltersContext>({
  filters: {},
  updateFilter: () => {},
  addFilter: () => {},
  clearFilter: () => {}
});

export const FiltersProvider: React.FC<FilterContextProps> = ({
  children,
  onFilterChange,
  initialFilters = {}
}) => {
  const filters = useRef(initialFilters);

  const updateFilter = (name: string, value: any) => {
    addFilter(name, value);
    onFilterChange(filters.current);
  };

  const addFilter = (name: string, value: any) => {
    filters.current = {
      ...filters.current,
      [name]: value
    };
  };
  const clearFilter = (name: string) => {
    if (filters.current[name] !== null && filters.current[name] !== undefined) {
      updateFilter(name, null);
    }
  };
  return (
    <FiltersContext.Provider
      value={{ filters, updateFilter, addFilter, clearFilter }}
    >
      {children}
    </FiltersContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And to be able to use this functions I use it as follows

```
<FiltersProvider onFilterChange={function (values: any): void {
  console.log("Function not implemented.");
} }>
<PrettyTable
  tableName="table_publications"
overlayFilter={
    <>
      <CountryFilter />
    </>
  }
  {...tableData}
/>
</FiltersProvider>
```

Now inside PrettyTable I have the following : (NOTE1****)

```
const { showDialog } = useDialog();
const { filters, addFilter } = useContext(FiltersContext);
console.log(filters?.current) //always "somename", "test" , only the function call in Confirm will save things. THe one inside COuntryFIlter (See below) wont

function showFilterSelector() {
  showDialog({
    title: "Filter Columns",
    message: <DialogContent />,
    cancel: {
      action: () => console.log("cancelled"),
      message: "Reset Filters"
    },
    confirm: {
      action: () => addFilter("somename", "test"), //I can see this calling addFilter, and after that "filters.current" has its value.
      message: "Apply Filters"
    },
    align: "start",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    wide: true
  });
}

useEffect(() => {
  debugger;
},[filters])

const DialogContent = () => {
  return (
    <Grid
      columns={["flex", "flex", "flex"]}
      justifyContent={"around"}
      gap="small"
    >

      {props.overlayFilter} -->  Prop found in the first code snippet, content of that component is in the last code snippet (below)
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

In the code above, im able to see the confirm action calling the function inside the provider, and it works just fine
But props.overlayFIlter contain the following:

Which is also using the same context inside

```
export const CountryFilter = ({...}) => {
  const { filters, addFilter, updateFilter, clearFilter } = useContext(FiltersContext);

  return (
  <SelectComponent 
    onChange={i => {
       addFilter("filter1","x") //This one is also being called supposedly in the context, but later I cant read it anywhere
}} /> )
```

But the above function despite calling the same context, the added data wont be able to be read in (NOTE1*** code snippet). I will only see the filter registered in the confirm action ("somename", "test")

What am I dont wrong? Am I using the contexts wrong?

Comment: Why are you cutting up your code example into small pieces and trying to explain in words how it fits together... ? Just post a [mre]. Super confusing.

Comment: Updating a ref doesn't re-render its react dependencies. Try changing filters from a ref to state.

Comment: @windowsill you are right, that makes sense, since ive noticed it doesnt rerender when it should